# Как получить информацию об адресе, который клиент вбил в строку при заходе на мой сайт? JS PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет!

Как мне получить адрес из строки браузера, который вбил клиент, чтобы перенаправить его на уже существующую или только что сгенерированную страницу, например, в таком случае:

Клиент вбивает: `exmaple.com/lelik` -  я отправляю ему страницу Лёлика

или

`example.com/sveta` - я отправляю ему страницу Светы

???

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам стоит посмотреть в сторону `.htaccess`?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Тогда при `example.com/sveta`, сервер будет запрашивать `example.com/index.php?url=sveta`.

При `example.com/sveta/lelik`, сервер будет запрашивать `example.com/index.php?url=sveta/lelik`.

Ну а там уже дело техники, получаете этот `$_GET['url']` и манипулируете.